# En las construcciones del tipo "me voy a " + verbo , ¿qué tipo de complemento es el verbo?

Tags: sintaxis

Tengo entendido que en las construcciones del tipo "me voy a " + lugar , el lugar es un complemento circunstancial de lugar. Qué sucede cuando en la oración en su lugar hay un verbo en lugar de un lugar, como por ejemplo en "me voy a comer"?

En las construcciones del tipo "me voy a " + verbo , ¿qué tipo de complemento es el verbo?

Comment: Mas interesante es: Voy a por pan. O: Voy a por vino.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es un complemento circunstancial, porque no es exigido por el verbo (véase el [§1.12f de la NGLE](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=PMJiCEHYlkSYtStT)). Se puede eliminar sin que la frase pierda su gramaticalidad (y sin que cambie mucho su significado): "Me voy". Esto lo diferencia de la perífrasis verbal "voy a comer".

La misma NGLE dice en el [§39.5](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=pGrZkxqBgqNztOZp) que la clasificación de los complementos circunstanciales no es universal dada la cantidad de ideas distintas que pueden expresar. Sin embargo, en este caso, yo me inclinaría por llamarlo **complemento circunstancial de finalidad**, porque "comer" es la finalidad de "irse". Se podría decir "Me voy para comer" con el mismo significado.

Comment: si, había visto en internet ese cuadro con el ejemplo del "para" y yo también pensé que podía ser ese caso.